# Comment dit-on "is it <un objet> ?" en français?

Tags: grammaire

Bonjour -

J'ai besoin d'aide avec la phrase suivante:  "Is it my cowardice?"

Ce serait une inversion simple, n'est-ce pas? Comme ça:

> Est-ce ma lâcheté ?

Ou est-ce que ce n'est pas correct ? Si ça c'est le cas, comment est-ce qu'on le dit ? Je pense que la réponse est simple mais je ne m'en souviens pas.

Comment: Dans quel contexte ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Est-ce ma lâcheté?"* est tout à fait correct. En français plus courant (mais moins correct...) on dirait *"Est-ce que c'est ma lâcheté?"*

Comment: Je te remercie beaucoup. Le français est ma première langue étrangère, ha ... je continue d'apprendre les points minces. Merci !!

Comment: On peut également dire "C'est ma lâcheté ?"

Comment: Le français courant n'en est pas moins « correct ». [Il y a beaucoup de préjugés qui pèsent sur la langue parlée : on a tendance à confondre langue écrite avec langue correcte, et langue parlée avec langue familière fautive (qui présente des fautes). C'est une confusion et une affirmation fausse.](http://html.rincondelvago.com/langue-francais.html)

Answer (score 4):

Il existe plusieurs niveaux (ou registres) de langue en français. Suivant celui qui est employé, des expressions possibles sont:

Soutenu, formel, écrit:

> – Est-ce ma lâcheté ? (voire le plus littéraire : « Est-ce ma couardise ? »)

Courant, parlé, standard:

> – Est-ce que c'est ma lâcheté ? (ou plutôt : « Est-ce que c'est parce que je suis lâche ? »)

Familier, parlé, relâché:

> – C'est parce que je suis lâche ?

Argot, vulgaire:

> – C'est parce que j'ai pas de couilles ?

Comment: Bien que la réponse acceptée ne soit pas fausse à strictement parler celle-ci est meilleure dans la mesure où elle contextualise les divers niveau de languepossible. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Vous devriez fournir plus de contexte. En anglais, il arrive que "is it" sous-entende "is it because of", ce qui pourrait être le cas dans l'exemple que vous fournissez. Auquel cas, il vaudrait mieux traduire explicitement en français:

> Est-ce à cause de ma lâcheté?

(synonymes envisageables: en raison de/dû à, couardise)